# How to record scroll position pre layout change in recycler view?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a opposite issue to everyone else. I have a chat type layout with recyclerview and textbar at the bottom (both in linear layout)

When text bar expands, recyclerview height is decreased as per layout, however it preserves the scroll position. I'd like to offset the scroll by the height delta, meaning  last visible item should be visible after text bar expands, not hidden behind it (scrolled away)

The problem is when to record this position as onScolled listener is also called automatically after such height change, so I get "post layout" valued

I tried subclassing LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren and calling the lastVisiblePosition pre and post super.onLayoutChildren but both are the same

I'm not sure what to do

Comment: try with Add this input mode in your manifest file inside your activity tag.

       android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"

Comment: Yea sorry I forgot to add Im drawing behind system bars so that flag doesnt work

Comment: For a better response please update your question as everyone is not going to read the comments

Comment: I tried turning of the behind the system drawing, so the flags you suggested can work, but the recycler view position is still kept, so it is irrelevant